# Copying new data into shared Geodatabase in ArcGIS for Server using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcobjects, modelbuilder, esri-geodatabase

How do I need to in order to publish a geodatabase into a server or just to copy new data into the server using ArcGis Server 10.1, ModelBuilder and .NET 2010.

Note : I have already a geodatabase published on the server but each time I have a new added data on the geodatabase they must be copied into the server. to be able to consult them on the map.

Do I need perhaps to a script ArcObjects, ModelBuilder or an addtional tool?

[image]

Comment: Hi Amine,
What do you mean about publishing a Geodatabase? Do you want to publish a map service pointing to your feature classes?
The normal way is just to publish a map service pointing to your Geodatabase. Then you can access your workspace directly from the MapServer object. 
If your new features are on the feature class, and the map application is consuming such feature class, the features appear directly on the map. There is no need to copy them, only refresh on the client side (map)