# Copying new data into shared Geodatabase in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, map-service, publishing

Similar to this question:

[Copying new data into shared Geodatabase in ArcGIS for Server using ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154233/how-to-copy-new-data-into-shared-geodatabase-in-arcgis-for-server-using-arcobjec) [closed]

I am wanting to know how to publish a map service without having to copy all of the data to the server because I added one new feature class to our enterprise GDB.

I have gone the route of creating a service definition file without sending up data to the server, and then publishing the sd from Catalog.  However, doing this it seems you have to then delete the existing service (the one I want to replace) and then recreate it from the sd file.  I then have to restart IIS because the indexing in the REST service is off.

Also, with 10.0 we were able to just restart the map service (and IIS) without having to go through all these extra steps and still get the desired result.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Have you verified the geodatabase folder location is registered with the data store?  You can also register your enterprise GDB directly to the datastore.

Comment: Best practice is to register enterprise and file geodatabases with the Server install, in which case the data can be used as-is.

Comment: Yes, it is registered.  I'm just looking for a way to either not copy all the data to the server when I publish, or not have to delete/recreate the map service.  I tried just restarting the existing map service (after adding the layer to the mxd), but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: "after adding layer to the mxd"  - which mxd did you add it to? AFAIK, arcgis server only uses [service definition](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/about-service-definition-files.htm) files - the mxd in the services directory is not read.

Comment: I guess maybe i'm not understanding why we need to "copy data to the server" after it has been registered.  So far, it's looking like I'll just have to recreate the sd file/map service every time.

Comment: @crmackey - I just reread your comment.  I didn't realize I had to register the folder location as well.  I will try that.

Comment: Did you register the File GDB directly?  If so, I did not know you could do that. I thought it had to be an enterprise database in order to do that.  However, we have a few services that use File Geodatabases and in that case we have registered the folder that contains them and the services published without copying the data to the server.

Comment: Enterprise GDB.  Which is why I didn't thing registering a folder would do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!  I have a read-only version and an admin version of the enterprise gdb.  Had to register the other version.  *The more you know!*

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you registered the enterprise geodatabase with your ArcGIS Server you can add as much data to the geodatabase as you want, and it will not be copied to the ArcGIS Server.

To republish a service, starting with ArcGIS 10.1 you can/should republish directly from ArcGIS Desktop environment, without having to manually save the SD file and then publish it from the web-interface. After making the Map Document, just go to File->Share As->Publish Service to open the service publishing wizzard. Select Overwrite existing service to replace the existing one with the new Map Service.

Comment: Overwriting the service from ArcMap still copies data to the server.  I have mxd's with over a hundred layers in them, and didn't want to reload the same data everytime.